# Where is Asp.net core 3.0 nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net-core

I went to Nuget.org to fetch Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 3.0.0 but didn't find it, Is there any reason for Microsoft for not pushing these packages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 is no longer shipped as nuget packages but a framework, which is included as a part of the SDK.

To reference it from a project that does not use the web sdks, use this in your csproj file inside an `<ItemGroup>` element, like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

This includes most packages that were formerly referenced from nuget.

Note that you cannot add it to a project that uses the web sdks, as it is already added by the sdk by default.

Comment: that doesn't work, and give error `The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' was not recognized`

Comment: Are you sure that your target framework is `netcoreapp3.0`? ASP.NET Core 3.0 targets .NET Core 3.0 only, not .NET Standard 2.1 or 2.0

Comment: You're right, I was targeting .NET Standard 2.1, thanks.