# HttpRequest.RouteValues property is not accessible from code but accessible from debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to create middleware which performs some checking for particular requests.

For example, I have such routes:

- `api/Test/{paramToCheck}/aaa`
- `api/Test/bbb/ccc`

and I have these requests:

- `http://some-host-and-port/api/Test/1234/aaa`
- `http://some-host-and-port/api/Test/bbb/ccc`

Now inside my middleware I want to check if request contains `{paramToCheck}` and get value of this parameter.

When I set breakpoint inside `InvokeAsync` I can see `httpContext.Request.RouteValues` property containing all needed data (`Keys` contains `"paramToCheck"` and `Values` contains its value).

But in code I can't access this property, I get error:

> Error CS1061: 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'RouteValues' and no accessible extension method 'RouteValues'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`var value = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["paramToCheck"];`

How can I access this property or how can I perform needed check?

Code:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware
    (
        RequestDelegate next
    ) => this._next = next;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var value = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["paramToCheck"]; // error here

        //... some logis with value

        await this._next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Middleware is inside `netstandard2.1` class library and it cannot be moved to api project as it is common and should be used by several api projects.

**UPDATE**

Seems like currently it cannot be achieved as `RouteValues` propery was added in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 3.0.0` which is inside `NetCoreApp 3` metapackage. And there is no possibility to install this package in `netstandard 2.1` project because the latest version is `2.2.0`.

Comment: sounds like you trying to access this from a service implementation which does not have access to httpContext, am i correct in saying to have this outside of your api project.

Comment: @Seabizkit, yes, I try to access it from `netstandard2.1` class library

Comment: @Seabizkit, I can access this property from api project. Can I access it somehow from `netstandard` (some nuget package)? Because it is common middleware which should be used by severap api projects.

Comment: this works `var routeData = ((dynamic)context.Request).RouteValues;`

Answer (score 7):

Just encountered the same problem today.

This is hacky but it works

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? routeValues = ((dynamic)context.Request).RouteValues as IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>;
```

Answer (score 7):

Using a class library, the answer for me was to upgrade to using .netcore 3.1's `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions v2.2`

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126758/852806), .net core 3 did away with all the small packages, so I replaced

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

with

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and then I could access the route like so:

```
HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["version"];
```

where `{version}` was set in the route.

Comment: HttpRequest.RouteValues does not exist in netstandard2.0 and this was needed when upgrading the project to net6.0.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you trying to access this from a service implementation which does not have access to httpContext, am i correct in saying to have this outside of your api project.

if you do `httpContext.Request.RouteValues["paramToCheck"];` in controller does it works... then to get it to work , do this in controller and pass the result to the lib.

httpContext has "binding"* to BaseController or ControllerBase... what ever its call.. basically the wiring which you are expecting is not done in your lib... so httpContext has no web context at all, there is a much better way to word this... all, but you get the just.

Comment: Thanks, but moving middleware in api project is not possible as it is common and should be used by several api projects. Is there some other way to achieve what I need?

Comment: I have `httpContext`, it is inside `InvokeAsync` of middleware

Comment: ok now looks like your maybe your not registering this correctly... "that should work!" well you should be able to get that to work....., show how you are wiring this up....

Comment: It is wired correctly because I set breakpoint inside `InvokeAsync` (when `var value = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["paramToCheck"];` is commected) and I can see `RouteValues` when breakpoint is hit.

Comment: I get compile time error indicating that `RouteValues` does not exists on `HttpRequest`.

Comment: tell me if https://rimdev.io/asp-net-core-routes-middleware/ helps you

Comment: The same issue with `GetRouteData()` - I get compile time error because there is not such method on `HttpContext`.

Comment: I assume that some reference is missed in my `netstandard` project, because if I move middleware to api project everything works well.

Comment: have you added the namespace to the lib... project... you will need to do this too..., httpContext will exist in a name space the lib will have to have these references... as well.

Comment: I have `applicationBuilder.UseRouting();             applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();` Which namespace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205432/discussion-between-seabizkit-and-dixy).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension `.GetRouteData()` from `RoutingHttpContextExtensions` which will provide you a `RouteData` instance. This extension is part of [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/) package.

The `RouteData` contains a property member of type `RouteValueDictionary` called **Values**.

```cs
var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData();

if (routeData.Values.TryGetValue("paramToCheck", out object value))
{
    // ... Do some logic with the value
}
```

To understand a bit more about the `RoutingHttpContextExtensions` and `RouteData` check the source code at 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/3.0/src/Http/Routing

Comment: This allowed me to implement this in netstandard2.0 instead of net6.0. Thank you!

Comment: This also works for net6.0 if you want to keep down on your overall package size as opposed to adding a whole framework reference

Answer (score 0):

Alexander Ivanov's answer:

```
routeValues = ((dynamic)context.Request).RouteValues as IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>;
```

worked for me, thanks! It took me a little to get it working, however, as the following packages were required:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions
- Microsoft.CSharp

Including this additional information in the hopes it saves someone some time.