# Get RouteValues from IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I extract the RouteValues from IHttpContextAccessor?

I have tried like this:

```
_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues
```

But I only get 'HttpRequest does not contain definition for RouteValues...'

I have the exact problem described here: [HttpRequest.RouteValues property is not accessible from code but accessible from debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610509/httprequest-routevalues-property-is-not-accessible-from-code-but-accessible-from)

I'm trying to get the route-values within my class library.

Comment: What's the target framework of your class library?

Comment: Can you explain (by way of a question edit) why solutions to the linked problem did not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Thanks to this author: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/May/15/Accessing-RouteData-in-an-ASPNET-Core-Controller-Constructor

Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

MyController.cs:

```cs
private readonly IActionContextAccessor _actionContext;

public MyController(IActionContextAccessor actionContext)
{
    _actionContext = actionContext;
}

public IActionResult MyAction()
{
    var routeValue = _actionContext.ActionContext.RouteData.Values;
}
```