# Cannot find SignalR HubOption MaximumReceiveMessageSize property in DotNetStandard 2.1 project

Tags: c#, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, .net-standard-2.1

I am trying to create a Nuget package targeting .NET Standard 2.1 to make the process of setting up a SignalR Hub easier. I have created an extension method for the IServiceCollection like so:

```
public static void ConfigureSignalR<THub>(this IServiceCollection services, bool enableDetailedErrors = true, int? maximumReceiveMessageSize = null) where THub : Hub
        {
            services.AddSignalR(o =>
            {
                o.EnableDetailedErrors = enableDetailedErrors;
            }).AddHubOptions<THub>(options =>
            {
                options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = maximumReceiveMessageSize;
            });
        }
```

but I cannot seem to find the property MaximumReceiveMessageSize when using the AddHubOptions method?  I have tried adding the following nuget packages:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions (v2.2.0)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR (v1.1.0)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (v3.1.1)

But none of them seem to provide the relevant property. Can anyone advise what I am missing?

Comment: I think this was added in ASP.NET Core 3.0, and they [don't really publish packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references) anymore. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126758/1320845) might help - you'd have to target `netcoreapp3.0`.