# In ASP.NET Core FromHeader is causing the Request.Body to be fully read

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

In ASP.Net Core, I have this action method:

```
[HttpPost("things")]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync()
{
    using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
    string body = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    int bodyLength = body.Length;
    return Ok();
}
```

It works just fine. The body is streamed, and I can read it all. However, as soon as I attempt to get a header:

```
[HttpPost("things")]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync(
    [FromHeader(Name = "X-Test")] string test)
{
    using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
    string body = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    int bodyLength = body.Length;
    return Ok();
}
```

The body is already at the end of the stream and zero bytes is read. Obviously I am reading from a header, which should not affect the request body. If I change the code to this:

```
[HttpPost("things")]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync()
{
    string test = Request.Headers["X-Test"].First();
    using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
    string body = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    int bodyLength = body.Length;
    return Ok();
}
```

The action begins to work again, and I am even reading the header. If I switch back to FromHeader it fails again. Obviously, FromHeader is doing something internally which is messing with the request body.

It is important for me to get this working with FromHeader so that Swagger continues to work. Without FromHeader, I am unable to specify a header value in Swagger.

So I began searching and I found this page:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18087

It appears others were having similar problems with using FromQuery, and some have worked around it by:

> Results in:
> System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> And is "fixed" with:
> [DisableFormValueModelBinding] and factories.RemoveType();
>
> Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=3.1.0.0
> Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0
>
> ...
>
> Double-check your DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute code to make sure that it's removing FormFileValueProviderFactory.

I went to try it to see if it made any difference but the latest version of those libraries visible to me in NuGet is 2.2.0 and 2.2.5 which is the latest stable and what I have installed. And this type (FormFileValueProviderFactory) does not exist in those libraries yet. Inspection using ILSpy shows it indeed is not there. VS does show my target framework is .NET Core 3.1.

In any case, I am not even sure this would solve my problem.

Anybody have any suggestions what could be going wrong for me?

Thanks!

Comment: What exact ASP.NET Core version are you targeting? 3.1 or 2.2? Check your `csproj` file. `FormFileValueProviderFactory` was introduced in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and is part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`. If your targeted framework is `netcoreapp3.1` you should be able so use `FormFileValueProviderFactory` without explicit package reference as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` is delivered as part of framework package. Since 3.0 ASP.NET Core is no longer shipped as nuget packages but a framework, which is included as a part of the SDK.

Comment: If you wrtiing up your code in a class library (.NET Core or .NET Standard) you have to set your targeted framework to `netcoreapp3.1` in order to use ASP.NET Core 3.1 packages. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58126671/where-is-asp-net-core-3-0-nuget-packages).

Comment: I can read header and body on my site with```<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>``` in ```.csproj ```

Comment: Yeah in my .csproj I also have: <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>. But also the latest version of NuGet is 2.2.5 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core) and does not have FormFileValueProviderFactory, and though MSFT says it was introduced in 3.0, is not in the only library available to me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.formfilevalueproviderfactory?view=aspnetcore-5.0. I am looking at it in ILSpy to confirm, and attempting to build against it anyway in VS fails as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed if I search for `FormFileValueProviderFactory` in the `ValueProviderFactories` in my `DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute`, I can find it by simply doing a `Where(p => p.GetType().Name == "FormFileValueProviderFactory").FirstOrDefault()`. Then if I remove it from the factories list, everything just works.

So the question now becomes why cannot I reference that type. Since I have the type pulled up I can look at the assembly being referenced and it is `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.10\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll`. This means it is not even using the NuGet at all, but is using this assembly. So I began removing older and unnecessary NuGet references when I discovered why this project is set up this way. There are some ASP.NET Core MVC utilities in a helper library, including the `DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute`. This library is currently configured to be `netstandard2.1`, which is why the ASP.NET Core stuff cannot be referenced.

To fix this, all I had to do was change the target framework to be `netcoreapp3.1` and add this to reference ASP.NET Core:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Everything works now.